# Setting posting and receving attributes when adding member to a group

Tags: python, google-groups-api

After adding a member to a group:

```
groupMember = {
 "email": sender,
 "role": "MEMBER",
}
directory_service.members().insert(groupKey=groupName,body=groupMember).execute()
```

I would like to set the following attributes for that same member:
- Email delivery (we want to set it to no mail)
- Posting permission (we want to set it to "Override: member is allowed to post")

I can't find python (or other languages) API for setting group member attributes other than these member resource attributes:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#member",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "email": string,
  "role": string,
  "type": string
}
```

Is there an API (python or other languages) to set "**Email delivery**" and "**Posting permission**" attributes for a specific group member?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to set group member email preferences.